# Where can I find the original code for the bog standard Exception class in python

Tags: python, class, exception

I'm digging around with some overriding of exception stuff in a project at work. And I'm having just the hardest time looking up what all the default methods and variables are inside the standard built in "Class Exception" in python. I've found just about every tutorial on the planet, and I've found python's docs about baseexception class, but I want to view the original class. inspect.getsource() does not work with built in classes, and about 45 minutes of google searching has not yielded any results. I know you can view the entire source code of python on github, but I legitimately would not know where to begin looking with the behemoth of directories there and search is proving useless.

can I get a hand?

I just want to view:

Class Exception()
"..."

Comment: You're looking for the C source code?

Comment: This seems like an xy problem. It might be helpful to show a [mcve] of what you're actually trying to do with your "overriding of exception stuff" to help direct you more specifically

Comment: @G.Anderson not really. Whether or not it actually ends up being the case that I need to override some core functionality, I want to use the opportunity to better understand the role base python functions have in the language on the whole. 

For example, I had assumed that, while the language was written in c, that classes were written in python and bundled with the interpreter. Now I know that the class Exceptions and BaseExceptions are actually written in C.

Comment: @gshpychka you see, that was actually news to me until now that it WAS in C. I knew that python (or at least cpython) was written in C, but I assumed that most of the "built in classes" were written in the language python itself and just bundled with the interpreter when you download python. I was not aware that it actually was written in C. That's cool to know. It explains why I was looking in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is it: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/exceptions.c

It is in C.